# Difference in gesture recognization between iPad simulator and device?

Tags: ios, ipad, simulator, gesture, gesture-recognition

I know there are stark differences in performance between the iOS simulator running on a desktop and the device.  However, does anyone know what kind of difference this or other settings has on gesture recognition/passing?

I have a few different gestures setup on overlayed UIScrollViews (I know, problems abound) in order to achieve complex paging/scrolling behaviours.  I have single-finger dragging scrolling up and down, and two-finger dragging paging left and right.  My gestures and the interaction between the UIScrollViews is flawless on the iOS simulator.  However, on the device it seems that things like two-finger drags are *usually* being registered as two single-finger events instead.  About 1 in 10 will work as it should.  I can elaborate on the scrollviews if necessary, but as it works seemingly perfect on the simulator I suspect this to be a simulator vs. device problem.  However I've not found much information on how gestures are recognized and passed, and always assumed something like that would be similar on both devices.

Normally I'd blame error in my fingers' movement in relation to the exactness of the simulator's touch points, but they're not exactly complex gestures...

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: How do you have your gestures set up?